# Getting an IEnumerable from a port.DataReceived Event and its subscriber method?

Tags: c#, serial-port, ienumerable, handler, grasshopper

I am trying to read data received from a device but I get the following error with line `DA.SetDataList(0, port.DataReceived);`:

`The best overloaded method match for Grasshopper.Kernel.IGH_DataAccess.SetDataList(int,System.Collections.IEnumerable) has some valid arguments.`

The SetDataList(int32, IEnumerable) is part of the Grasshopper Kernel. `port.DataReceived` is an event and therefore not a valid IEnumerable argument, it stores a list of data in an output parameter during GH_Component.SolveInstance(). I have set up a subscriber method portdatareceived which gives me strings. How can I get an IEnumerable from this method?

```
  SerialPort port;

   protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
    {
    string gcode = default(string);
    DA.GetData(0, ref gcode);

    port = new SerialPort(selectedportname, selectedbaudrate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); 
    port.DtrEnable = true;   
    port.Open();            
    port.DataReceived += this.portdatareceived;

    if (gcode == null)
    {
        AddRuntimeMessage(GH_RuntimeMessageLevel.Warning, "Specify a valid GCode");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        DA.SetDataList(0, port.DataReceived);
    }    
    }

  private void portdatareceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
       string line = port.ReadExisting();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the line variable in the subscriber method a field and accessing it from the SetDataList method works:

```
SerialPort port;
string myReceivedLines;

   protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
  {

    string gcode = default(string);
    DA.GetData(0, ref gcode);

    port = new SerialPort(selectedportname, selectedbaudrate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    port.DtrEnable = true;   
    port.Open();            
    port.DataReceived += this.portdatareceived;

    if (gcode == null)
    {
        AddRuntimeMessage(GH_RuntimeMessageLevel.Warning, "Specify a valid GCode");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        DA.SetDataList(0,  myReceivedLines);
        port.WriteLine(gcode);
    }    
              }

    private void portdatareceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        myReceivedLines = port.ReadExisting();
    }
```

Comment: Cool,  This is the kind of thing I was trying to get at with my answer but I didn't know all the details.  Good work!

Answer (score 1):

With this code:

```
port.DataReceived += this.portdatareceived;
```

Seem `port.DataReceived` is an *event*, whereas, your method needs `IEnumerable`:

```
IGH_DataAccess.SetDataList(int,System.Collections.IEnumerable)
```

To solve this, you need to call this method inside `portdatareceived` by getting correct data from event argument.

Comment: Thanks Cuong Le, I am not sure how I could get the right IEnumerable data from the event. I have adapted the question to your reply.

Comment: @ArthurMamou-Mani: could you post `portdatareceived` in here?

Comment: It is at the end of the code.

Comment: @ArthurMamou-Mani: Could you also post method: SetDataList?

Comment: SetDataList(Int32, IEnumerable) is extracted from the Grasshopper Kernel, it stores a list of data in an output parameter during GH_Component.SolveInstance().

Comment: @ArthurMamou-Mani: seem not enough info for me, you just refer in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx. Try: DA.SetDataList(0, new[] { line });

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about GrassHopper, so this could be completely wrong.

Because `port.DataReceived` is an event I don't think you really want it as an IEnumerable.  Instead what you want is to wait for the event to be raised, and then perhaps the arguments passed in to this event will contain the data for your datalist.

So find the definition of `this.portdatareceived` and try to convert one of its arguments into an IEnumberable.  The code might look vaguely something like:

```
private void DataReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable hopefullyThisIsYourData = (IEnumerable)e;
    DA.SetDataList(0, hopefullyThisIsYourData);  
}
```

You could add a break point here to find out what is in `e`, and fix the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I already have a subscriber method called portdatareceived at the end of the code. The problem is that the SetDataList method has to be within the SolveInstance method.

Comment: Sorry, your existing `portdatareceived` event handler is the one I meant.

Comment: Thanks @buhbuh, unfortunately, I can only place the SetDataList() method within the SolveInstance one. Also IEnumerable inside the subscriber method requires an out T parameter?